# Grimmett and Stirzaker 3.8.3 p71

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be random geometric random variables with respective parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ show that:

$P(X+Y=z) = \frac{\alpha \beta \{(1-\beta)^{z-1} -(1- \alpha)^{z-1} \}}{\alpha - \beta}$

The first part of the proof on the lhs below is easy but I can't see how they get from there to the rhs.

$\sum_{r=1}^{z-1} \alpha(1- \alpha)^{r-1}\beta(1-\beta)^{z-r-1}=\frac{\alpha \beta \{(1-\beta)^{z-1} -(1- \alpha)^{z-1} \}}{\alpha - \beta}$

It would seem that you could use the expression for the sum of geometric series $\frac{1-f^n}{1-f}$ where f is a 0 < fraction < 1?

$\alpha\beta(\frac{1-(1-\alpha)^{r-2}}{\alpha})(\frac{1-(1-\beta)^{r-2}}{\beta})$

I'm I on the right track?
I can't seem to get from this to the desired expression.

Thanks

Baz

Comment: You should mention if $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not.